# For questions put On Hold, why is "on-hold" included in the URL of the question's title?

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions

When a question is put on hold (i.e., closed for a reason other than duplicate), the title links to a URL that ends with “`-on-hold`”.  For example, [this question (Am trying to connect my laptop LAN connection)](https://superuser.com/questions/612198/am-trying-to-connect-my-laptop-lan-connection) has been put on hold, and its title:

[image]

links to `http://superuser.com/questions/612198/am-trying-to-connect-my-laptop-lan-connection-on-hold`.  The link works, of course –– in fact, if you follow the link, the “`-on-hold`” gets stripped off –– but closed questions never did this before, and duplicates still don’t.

Comment: I think this is *possibly* a bug, albeit a minor one (as even clicking links generated by the `share` button, like [this one](http://superuser.com/q/612198/6887), end up being expanded to a "normal" looking one as the first link in the OP (I'd assume it simply rewrites the URL once the question ID is deemed valid).  Even if this is not by design, I'd argue that it's (fortunately) just a cosmetic bug and minor annoyance.

Comment: Do we know if the `-on-hold` link will still work when the question is no longer on hold?

Comment: @Excellll you can append whatever you want after the question ID and it'll work, e.g. http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6920/for-questions-put-on-hold-why-does-excellll-ask-questions-that-I-need-to-give-examples-for

Comment: @nhinkle haha ok

Answer (score 3):

This will be fixed in the next build, thanks for the report!